# AJAX username check don't pass value

Tags: ajax, post, silverstripe

I am trying to make validation of a username field in Silverstripe 3. Ajax checks if username exist and if exist, shows "this name is taken" via ajax.

But problem is, that no value is passed to variable via Ajax. $_POST['username'] is empty.

**So my code in controller:**

```
    public function checkuser1(){

      $Params = $this->getURLParams();      

if($Params['ID'] == '1'){

            if (Director::is_ajax()) {

                  $username = $_POST['username']; // Seems that I dont receive any value from input vie ajax

                  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
                  $check_for_username = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM Member WHERE UserName='$username'");
                  if(mysql_num_rows($check_for_username))
                  {
                     return '1';
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     return '0';
                  }

            }
            else {
               return Director::redirect(Director::baseURL());
            }                   

   }
}


public function checkuser(){

      return $this->checkuser1();

}
```

**And JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Form_RegistrationForm_UserName").change(function(){
$(".container .inner .top .right").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> checking...");

               var username = $("#Form_RegistrationForm_UserName").val();
               var dataString = 'username='+ username;

                  $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"http://localhost/mysite/member/checkuser/1/",
                        data:dataString,
                        success:function(server_response){
                           if(server_response == '0'){
                              $(".container .inner .top .right").html("Username available");
                           }
                           else{
                              $(".container .inner .top .right").html("Username already taken");
                           }
                        }
                      });

               });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your

`data:dataString`

to

`data: { username: username }`

and make sure to verify that the `username` var actually holds the username value before passing it.

Comment: Did what you said, checked if it holds value, and all seems to be fine. Just don't get it.. Maybe it is something specific how Silverstripe works with ajax?

Comment: perhaps try getting the $_POST variable outside of your function? do your dev tools say that the username value is being passed in the request header/body?

Comment: Got it working :) changed code to Silverstripe more style and know it works :) `if($check_for_username = DataObject::get_one("Member", "`UserName` = '". Convert::raw2sql($_POST['username']) . "'")){         
        echo '1';
       }
       else
       {
        echo '0'; 
       }`